# Add standard top links with language switcher magento

Tags: php, magento

How can I add top links with a language switcher beside it, currently using RWD theme style which has the top links in a drop down box?

Comment: please paste the code what you have tried.

Comment: http://yaubrothers.xist2test.com/index.php/products.html This is the site, has you can see the links aren't working, also the language switcher is floated to the left